# How to implement a second HttpPost in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, http-post

From my WP8 app I have a button that sends a file to my MVC WCF service. The problem is that I want to have another button that sends a file to the service, which does something different with the second file. For example, here is what I want my MVC to look like:

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Index()  
{ 
    foreach (string upload in Request.Files)  
    {
        //do something with upload
    }
}

[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Index()  
{  
    foreach (string upload in Request.Files)  
    {
        //do something with the second upload
    }
}
```

I just can't seem to figure how the MVC can differentiate between the two files that are uploaded separately. How does it know which ActionResult the uploaded file will go into? What would need to be added in order to guide the uploaded file to its intended ActionResult?

This sends the file from my WP8 app:

```
    private async void UploadFile()
    {
        //byte[] picbyte = photoStream.ToArray();
        //photoStream.Read(picbyte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(photoStream.Length));
        //photoStream.Close();

        //string connstr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ImageDB; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa";
        //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);

                try       
                {           
                    // Make sure there is a picture selected           
                    if (photoStream != null)         
                    {               
                        // initialize the client           
                        // need to make sure the server accepts network IP-based      
                        // requests.            
                        // ensure correct IP and correct port address           
                        var fileUploadUrl = @"http://localhost:54931/fileupload";            
                        var client = new HttpClient();             
                        // Reset the photoStream position           
                        // If you don't reset the position, the content lenght            
                        // sent will be 0           
                        photoStream.Position = 0;            
                        // This is the postdata           
                        MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();        
                        content.Add(new StreamContent(photoStream), "file", fileName);           
                        // upload the file sending the form info and ensure a result.         
                        // it will throw an exception if the service doesn't return           
                        // a valid successful status code           
                        await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content)            
                            .ContinueWith((postTask) =>                 
                            {                
                                postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();        
                            });        
                    }          
                    // Disable the Upload button        
                    btnUpload.IsEnabled = false;         
                    // reset the image control           
                    imgSelectedImage.Source = null;         
                    // Display the Uploaded message       
                    txtMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;     
                }     
                catch       
                {           
                    // Display the Uploaded message      
                    txtError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;    
                }


    }
```

Comment: use different names for your methods.  You have to anyways, that won't compile.

Comment: But still, how do you tell the upload to got to its intended method? is it from the app that sends it? If so I will add the code for that if it helps.

Comment: You'll have to route it to the correct method.  Set up routing to use the `controller` and `action` in the URL

Comment: Is this done from the app that sends it then? I've added that to the question just in case.

Comment: Assuming `fileupload` is your controller, then call `localhost:54931/fileupload/<your method name>`

Comment: @Adithya, Thank you so much. I figured that's what it was, but everything I was finding online was so much more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing different things with your files, just name your action differently, you can then upload the file to the different urls, for Index() it'll be /, and for the other say DoSomethingElse() it'll be /DoSomethingElse

Comment: I was wondering about the index. Thank you for the clear answer.

Comment: pleasure to help out :), upvote if you liked my answer, thanks